# RViz won't refresh my TF tree

Tags: rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I roslaunch something that broadcasts a TF, then launch RViz, I can visualize the TF in RViz. However, if I then restart the launch file, the new TF is not picked up. I need to also restart RViz to get the new TF.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189762/rviz-won%27t-refresh-my-tf-tree/) by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to restart RViz *whenever you start a new roscore*. RViz looks for a roscore upon startup. After that time, the roscore remains fixed.

This means that if you are using a launch file to launch everything, including the ROS Master, then whenever you relaunch the file you will also need to relaunch RViz. A better way to use RViz is to launch your roscore and RViz separately. Then you can keep them both open for the duration of your session.

---

Originally posted by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) with karma: 205 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-08-11**:
Apparently I don't have enough points to accept my own answer, but I wanted to post this here for others.